# asp.net:specify errors of MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError  using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Maybe the question sounds silly.
Who is the provider,in the above statement?
Is it the programmer who provides the error needed,the user that creates a membership or someone else? 
Specifically, i want to show error when the user types more than the maxlength characters as below:
ps. find the line with * in the geterrormessage method...

```
UsernameTextbox.MaxLength = 15;
    if (UsernameTextbox.Text.Length > UsernameTextbox.MaxLength)
    {
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;
        Msg.Text = GetErrorMessage(status);
    }


public string GetErrorMessage(MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
   switch (status)
  {


  case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
    return "Username already exists. Please enter a different user name.";


  case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
    return "A username for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

  case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

  case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

  case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

  case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

  case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";
   //****** STAR LINE:i want to show the following message but i don't know if the-->
  //-->the provider error method can let me do this
  case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
    return "field outreached the maximum length of characters which is:";

  case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

  default:
    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide some code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Provider is the default MembershipProvider which is built in. You can specify your own implementation by creating a class which derives from MembershipProvider.

Take a look at this tutorial on the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication Provider "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" returns an error.

For more info http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550